# Units for the Integral of a Velocity Function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, unit-of-measure

What would be the units for the integral of a velocity function? More specifically the units for this integral:

$$\frac1{12}\int_0^{12}v(t)dt$$

where $v(t)$ is a velocity function in meters per second.

I think it should be in meters, as velocity is the first derivative of displacement. My calc teacher says that this would yield a velocity with meters per second as the unit, as this would be the average value of the function. She says that $\int_0^{12}v(t)$ would yield a displacement (meters as the unit), so I'm confused about how multiplying it by $\frac1{12}$ would change the units.

Answer (score 1):

The integral does represent the displacement. I believe that $\frac1{12}$ is not just a constant, however; I believe the fraction represents $\frac1{12\text{ seconds}}$ which would explain why the units is meters/second.

Comment: Ok, I get this now. But how would I know if $\frac1{12}\int_0^{12}v(x)dx$ would be referring to $\frac1{12}$ or $\frac1{12 seconds}$ without any other context?

Comment: We should make the educated guess that $\frac{1}{12\text{ seconds}}$ is intended, since then this expression represents the average velocity from time 0 s to time 12 s, which is a thing you might be interested in knowing. If the $\frac{1}{12}$ were unit-less, then the expression would just be one twelfth of the displacement over this time interval, which is probably not something you care about.

Comment: I understand. So if we wanted to be explicit (rather than forcing the reader to make an educated guess) we could include units in the fraction to make it clear whether the whole thing refers to the average value or one-twelfth of the displacement

Answer (score 0):

The limits of integration (0 and 12) have units of seconds (they are values of $t$), so the 1/12 has units of inverse seconds.

Comment: If 1/12 has units of inverse seconds, shouldn't it be written as 1/12s or 12s^-1? Not just 1/12? I'm just confused about how the seconds seemingly appear out of nowhere.

Comment: Yes; if you want to explicitly write the units on all numerical quantities that have units (which is a good idea if you're trying to understand what's going on with the units!), then it should really be written as 1/(12 s) or (12 s)^-1, and the limits of integration should be written as 0 s and 12 s.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You're integrating differential displacements, given by the products of instantaneous velocities and differential times. Thus the integral is also a displacement.

Comment: So my teacher is incorrect about $\frac1{12}\int_0^{12}v(t)dt$ being a velocity? It is a displacement?

Comment: @wogchamp5 Yes, she was wrong about that, since $v(t)$ represents velocity and $\mathrm dt$ a differential amount of time.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't going insane. Will be talking to her now that I'm sure of my answer.